# Does lithium exist in near earth objects?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, elements, nucleosynthesis

Do we know if lithium exists in near Earth Object material and if so might it be economic to mine for future Earth-based transport?

Comment: Hi Andy. I suspect your question would get more attention on the [Space Exploration Stack Exchange](http://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Lithium is used in modern batteries because it is relatively easy from a technological POV. Potentially better metals are Aluminium, Magnesium and Sodium, and a lot of work is being done on them right now.

Comment: Lithium a exists on Earth, which is a pretty 'near Earth' object. It is not particularly rare.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, lithium certainly exists in near-Earth objects. But whether it is financally viable to go and get it is a question outside the scope of Physics SE (but I doubt it is in the forseeable future),

I suppose you could define near-Earth objects (or at least a subset of those) being objects that actually impact the Earth. From that point of view, a lot of what we know about elemental abundances in the Solar System, particularly the "pristine" abundances before differentiation and other processes changed them in planetary bodies, are obtained from meteorites.

A well-cited reference for meteoritic abundances is [Lodders (2003](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/375492/fulltext/57586.text.html). Their Table 1 lists the abundances deduced from CI Chondrites (meteoritic abundances) and, for comparison, from analysis of the photsophere of the Sun.

Lithium is a particularly interesting element in this regard because it has a much higher abundance in meteorites, which essentially matches what we think is the current abundace of lithium in the interstellar medium. This abundance is expressed in terms of *number* of lithium atoms/nuclei as $A({\rm Li} = 3.28\pm 0.06$ on the usual logarithmic astronomical scale where hydrogen ($A({\rm H}$) would be 12.

The abundance of lithium in the solar photosphere is only $1.10\pm  0.10$ and this is because lithium is burned in nuclear reactions in the deep solar interior and the depleted material gradually mixed to the photosphere over billions of years.